# Java List vs ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

As a C++ oldtimer I have managed to solve my problem but I can not wrap my head around the underlying Java mechanisms here:

```
Vector<Object> x = new Vector<Object>();        // OK
ArrayList<Object> y = new ArrayList<Object>();  // OK
List<Object> zzz = new ArrayList<Object>();     // OK solves problem below but question remains
List<Object> z = new List<Object>();            // WHY? Compiler error: Cannot instantiate
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`List` is an interface, somewhat like a class with some `= 0` methods in C++. You can't instantiate it.

But `ArrayList<T>` "inherits" `List<T>` (or in Java terms, implements it), so those references are assignment-compatible.

Comment: @Adam - wait till you get on to wildcards in Java generics! :) The answers take a little longer to appear.

Comment: Yeah Daniel, I have seen the wonderful little http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html Anyway your answer was very much to the point and I DO know java interfaces just didnt think of List<> in those terms :)

Answer (score 5):

List is an interface, you cannot initialize it. `ArrayList` implements `List`, so you can assign an `ArrayList` instance to a `List` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Because List is an Interface and in Java you cannot instantiate an Interface.
You can only instantiate a class.

ArrayList is a class that's implementing List<> that's why you can instantiate it.
:)

Answer (score 2):

The `List` is an interface. You cannot create in instance of an interface using `new` operator. That's why the line `List<Object> z = new List<Object>();` gives error. Only classes can be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

List isn't class it's an Interface and you can't instantiate the interface object.

ArrayList is the class which was implement the List interface so can able to instantiate the ArrayList object and assign to the List object

Answer (score 1):

"Interface" is like a protocol that an object must comply with.

Comment: Interesting approach to use protocols as an analogy. Although a little bit more text what "it" is and what not might things a little clearer.

Comment: I never heard protocol in this context. But I understand what you mean. I prefer the term contract: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract

Comment: @Adam I agree, contract is a better word.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an `interface` and an interface can't be instantiated.

It's used to implement polymorphism. i.e. a reference of interface type can hold object of any class that `implements` it.

```
List<Object> zzz = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

it works, cause ArrayList implements List.