# diferrence between arraylist and List

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the diference between using Array List and a List. Actually Java throws me an exception when I want to instantiate the List with istself, in fact I have to do it with a ArrayList.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a List vs. an ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867484/what-is-a-list-vs-an-arraylist) and [Java List vs ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309093/java-list-vs-arraylist).

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an exception and not compile time error when you instantiate the list with itself?

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an *abstract* type - a java `interface`. An interface defines what methods may be found on an object that implements `List`.

An `ArrayList` is a concrete implementation of the `List` interface (that uses an array internally to store the elements, hence the name).

An `ArrayList` is a `List`, but a `List` is not *necessarily* an `ArrayList`. There are other implementations, such as `LinkedList`.

See [*Liskov substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: i'll steal liskov substitution principle xD

Comment: @nachokk Actually, it's a great link to just throw in an answer to give it that encyclopedic, authoritative feel :)

Answer (score 0):

**List** is an interface, **ArrayList** is a class that implements **List**. You can't instantiate an interface.

Comment: well, you almost can instantiate an interface - with an anonymous class.

Comment: Technically an anonymous class is a *class*, but it feels like you're instantiating an interface.

Answer (score 0):

A List is a general type of object known as an interface. There are many types of lists including but not limited to ArrayList and LinkedList. The list interface provide handles to a set of methods required for manipulating a list without knowing what type of list it is. Any type of list can be assigned to a variable of type List. But list itself cannot be instantiated because it is only an interface and not an implementation. See the Java list tutorial for more information. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws an exception cause `List` is abstract you can't instantiate something abstract.

**List is an Interface**. Here you define *the contract* the behaviour signature of this type.

ArrayList is a List , cause `implements List`, **ArrayList is a concrete implementation**  so then have all methods defined by the List interface.

In Java you can apparently instantiate an interface making `anonymous classes`  but you really have a concrete class that implements `List` contract with no-name (that's why the anonymous name).

Here is an example

```
List list = new List(){

            @Override
            public boolean add(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void add(int arg0, Object arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(Collection arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean addAll(int arg0, Collection arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void clear() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean contains(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsAll(Collection arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Object get(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int indexOf(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterator iterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int lastIndexOf(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public ListIterator listIterator() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public ListIterator listIterator(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean remove(Object arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Object remove(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean removeAll(Collection arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean retainAll(Collection arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Object set(int arg0, Object arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public List subList(int arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object[] toArray(Object[] arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        };
```

As @Bohemian says, if you make your own list implementation you have to take care about [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle),to don't break this and follow the contract.